# How to use playframework compiled from source

Tags: playframework

I downloaded the source from github and built the playframework now I want to run the playframework from command line but do not know how?

The last compiled playframework which I can download from play site is ver 2.2.6. I want to use the last playframework how to do it?

**`UPDATE`**

When downloading the latest playframework code from the github it was not downloading the whole code as there is folder named `hosts` and this name is blocked by McAfee antivirus on my Windows 10 system. Hence I started a virtual Ubuntu OS and in that I checked out the latest code and compiled it. But still it is only generating the jar files not the batch file to run it from command line. On further analysis I found that all the jars are of 1KB size. While compiling I do not get any error it is successful and completed in few seconds.

Comment: Typically, people use sbt to run the play framework. If you have an sbt project, you merely need to specify play as a plugin, and it will automatically be downloaded. Is there anything that prevents you from going this standard way? https://playframework.com/download

Comment: I have a sbt project, when I run the project it does not start. Once I downloaded the older play framework 2.2.6 and added its path to environment variable then the project ran. But I need the latest framework for my project.

Comment: In the link I shared above, there are some instructions on how to get the latest version running. Please follow those steps and ask again if it doesn't work. You're going to have to share the exact steps you did though, as well as the errors you get. Play 2.2.6 is very old -- don't use that if you have the choice.